# Gradle build finished with 3 errors

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, r.java-file

I am working on Android studio for quite a while and few days back I encountered a weird problem. 
While working on an app implementing a database, I clicked on run app to check, then the build stopped immediately and gave me an error **gradle build finished with 3 errors**.

Another time, while the gradle was building the project, `R.java` class gets opened up in a new tab on its own and one of the variable's name gets an error.
Even though the screen showed that I should not tamper the `R.java` file contents.

I tried renaming that mistyped variable to its correct name again (variable's correct name is `et_linked_username` and it showed `et-linked-username` in `R.java` class) and rebuilt the project but NOTHING WORKS, ITS ALL THE SAME.

I believe something is wrong with the project itself, because its working absolutely fine on other projects.

I have included the image as a link below :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should never change the R.java file, its a system generated file.
Try to clean your project and rebuild it. You need to go to tools and access the options there.